# Brightness changes are shown by the indicator but have no effect on the display (Lubuntu, Intel card)

Tags: lubuntu, brightness, intel, backlight, xbacklight

I have tried many of the proposed solutions that I could find on the web, but any of them worked for me. I detail here my problem and some of the things that I tried:

**Relevant details:**

TOSHIBA NB200

`Lubuntu 16.04` and `18.04`

Output of `ls /sys/class/backlight/`:

`acpi_video0  intel_backlight`

**Problem:**

When trying to adjust the brightness of the laptop, the *brightness indicator* appears in the upper right corner reflecting the changes, but **no variation occurs on the actual display brightness**.

**What I have tried:**

- Use the **default keyboard keys** to adjust the brightness.
- Create/edit the `xorg.conf` file (using as "Identifier" either `card0` or the output of `xrandr --verbose`, see e.g. [here](https://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/301724/xbacklight-not-working) in the answer provided by Lorem Ipsum)
- Use the `xbacklight` package and change the brightness with
  `$ xbacklight -inc 10` and
  `$ xbacklight -dec 10`
- Manually edit the file `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`

In the last two, if I later use the default keyboard keys to adjust the brightness, I can see how the changes were applied, but again no variation occurs on the actual display brightness.

I would really appreciate your help! Any suggestion?